# Server stops responding to requests after too many in a session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, server

I have web app that uses frequent `$.ajax()` calls to transmit data to and from the server.  This runs locally between a virtual machine host and client.

The problem I'm having is that it seems to cut out after making certain number of consecutive calls in a session (no actual number has been determined).  This is can be seconds or minutes.

I tried assigning my `$.ajax()` calls to objects so they could be deleted, eg.:

```
myApp.ajaxRegistry.myAjax = $.ajax({
     url: '/path/to/server',
     error: function() {
          delete myApp.ajaxRegistry.myAjax;
     }
     success: function() {
          delete myApp.ajaxRegistry.myAjax;
     }
});
```

I thought that may have improved it, but it could just be coincidence.  It still fails frequently.

I've monitored the server access log when these failures occur, I can see that it's not even making the request.  There are no Javascript errors in the browser console.

**EDIT**

The browser's network logger indicates that it *is* making the request, but *server* is not responding (according to apache's access log).  After a few minutes, it starts responding again, so I'm thinking there is configuration on the server.

It might also be worth noting that the virtual machine server frequently loses time (some sort of annoying VirtualBox "feature"), so I wonder if that might be related.

**UPDATE**

I think my hunch about the server time may have been right.  I finally managed to get `ntp` to work properly on the VM and I haven't encountered this problem for a few weeks now.

Comment: There's no inherent limit. In what way do things "stop working"? How can you tell it stopped?

Comment: What do the response look like in JavaScript for a failed request?

Comment: @Pointy: The app stops behaving as expected.  I trigger a request while watching the server log and entries are not being added to the log.

Comment: Well, without seeing any code it's going to be hard to say. Something between whatever it means to "trigger a request" and the request actually happening must be going wrong.

Comment: What does browser dev tools network show you? Or console errors? Could be overloading server memory also

Comment: What is the purpose , expected result  of `delete myApp.ajaxRegistry.myAjax;` ?

Comment: @guest271314: shot in the dark, mostly ;)

Comment: What is purpose of the line ? What do you mean by "cut off" ? Can you reproduce the issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co ?

Comment: @charlietfl: I watched the browser's network log when this occurred again, and it *is* attempting to make a request.  But there is no corresponding entry in the apache access log on the server.  So now I'm thinking it's an apache configuration.  Interesting: I let it sit for a few minutes and it started responding again.

Comment: sounds like you might need to use web sockets ... or cut way down on ajax requests

Comment: @charlietfl: I'll look into that.  However, this is a local application for internal use (it's literally just me), so I'm first going to see if there's a server config that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have the answer in a separate post: the server time needs to be accurate (at least in this context) or the AJAX requests get confused.